# MsSQL и C# в VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server

Мне понадобилась локальная база данных. Возможно, я, что-то неверно понял и по этому выбрал *MsSql local*. В общем, мне нужно локальное хранилище данных, переносимое вместе с проектом. Думаю я выбрал верно.

Я создал архитектуру будущей базы. Весь проект у меня разделен на сборки. Создал *ДАЛ* библиотеку в одном решении с *.exe*. Далее я решил протестировать данную базу и архитектуру. Создал еще одну библиотечную консоль *Application* и начал писать тесты. Изначально мне нужно было написать *генерилку* данных и когда с ней было покончено, я получил ряд проблем. Я обнаружил, что запускается `ConnectionStrings` только из проекта тестов и мне показалось это очень странным.

Как запустить `ConnectionStrings` *ДАЛ* сборки я не понял. *Конекшен* в обоих случаях лежит одинаковый, но работает он видимо исходя из контекста по разному.

Вот конекшен:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
    <add name="DalClickBot.Properties.Settings.ClickBotDataBaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ClickBotDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Аномалия заключается в следующем. Файл базы данных копируется в тестовую сборку и вся вставка данных сохраняется в эту сборку в *бд*, а *бд* в *ДАЛ* лежит не тронутое *оО*.

Сам файл базы не лежит не в проекте, не в *дебаге*. О его существовании я узнаю только открыв *SQL Server Object Explorer*. Ни в обозревателе серверов, негде больше его просто нет *оО*. Я добился записи в базу данных в *Дал* таким способом:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=        (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ClickBotDataBase.mdf;    Integrated Security=True"))
        {
           // conn.ConnectionString =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DalClickBot.Properties.Settings.Click    BotDataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            //Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Сказать честно, он меня не очень устраивает, хотелось бы из *конфига*. Когда я так делаю, то попутно ловлю вот такую ошибку:

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка
Предупреждение      Не удалось скопировать "C******\DalClickBot    \ClickBotDataBase_log.ldf" в "bin\Debug\ClickBotDataBase_log.ldf".     Начинается повторная попытка 1 в 1000 мс. Процесс не может получить доступ к     файлу "bin\Debug\ClickBotDataBase_log.ldf", так как этот файл     используется другим процессом. TestDalClickBot
```

Вопросы таковы:

1. почему происходит копирование и правильно ли это *оО*?
2. если это не правильно, то как это исправить?
3. как брать `ConnectionStrings` из *Дал* сборки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте информативные метки, по которым можно чётко определить, кто может знать ответ на ваш вопрос. Специалисты по C#, VisualStudio и MySQL существуют, а "специалисты по ошибкам" - нет. Помните, мало кто читает ленту на главной, - большинство участников просто подписаны на вопросы по определённой метке. Ставя подобную метку вы уменьшаеть шанс, что на ваш вопрос ответят.

Comment: @Risto, прикол в том, что сейчас там висит правка от пользователя Владимир и она снова возвращает метку `ошибка` :)

Comment: @Visman и нафиг, интересно? Автор уже и сам исправил, то есть со мной согласился (Каюсь, повесил MySQL, был неправ).

Comment: пробовали заменить `|DataDirectory|` на полный путь?

Answer (score 3):

1. Вы все делаете верно. Просто нужно понимать что ваш DAL - это всего лишь библиотека. Приложение запускается в контексте вашего тестового проекта и настройки берутся из его конфига. Именно поэтому вы и должны дублировать в него connection string изначально объявленный в DAL.
2. Для корректных относительных путей в connection string введен параметр DataDirectory. Например в ASP.NET проектах он указывает на директорию App_Data. Можно задавать  DataDirectory программно, при старте приложения. Т.е. определить путь по которому будет лежать ваша БД и установить его в настройках.

   ```
   var path = ...
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
   ```

Либо можно задать абсолютный путь к mdf файлу. В обоих случаях ваш connection string будет корректен. Более подробно о DataDirectory ищите в MSDN.

3. Декларативно никак. Можно программно объявить метод в DAL, который будет читать connection string из конфига DAL. И полученный результат использовать для создания соединения с БД.

Ситуация нормальная. Ваш DAL это повторно используемая библиотека. Она не должна зависеть от деталей окружения. Грубо говоря - куда ей сказали туда она и пишет.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо признаться честно я чуть с ума не сошел )